# How do I associate an ID with a content of a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example I have a HTML table...

```
name | grade  | action
bob  | 1.0    | [button class="button" id='1']
jack | 2.0    | [button class="button" id='2']
john | 3.0    | [button class="button" id='3']
```

When I click the button,

to get the id...

```
$(function(){
$('.button').click(function()
var buttonid = this.id
});
});
```

so if I were to press buttonid 1 how do I get the name 'bob' without having to open the database?

Additionally if I press the button how do I get the values in each column? i.e. If I press button 3 how do I get grade 3.0 or get both name and grade?

Script that generates the row of the table

```
while(){ 
echo '<tr>'; 
echo '<td>'.$name.'</td>'; 
echo '<td>'.$grade.'</td>'; 
echo '<td> <input type="button" class="button" id="'.$id'"</td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: I think you've oversimplified your code. In the example click handler, `buttonid` will only ever be `'button'`. Could you show us the markup for an actual row in the HTML table?

Comment: Also you missed a `{` and IDs may not start with a digit.

Comment: Actually `#button.click` will never work as nothing has an ID of `button`

Comment: @MattBall The rows of the table are generated in a while loop `while(){ echo '<tr>'; echo'<td>'.$name.'</td>'; echo '<td>'.$grade.'</td>'; echo '<td> <input type="button" class="button" id="'.$id'"</td>';}` @pimvdb @rickyduck Sorry about that I changed my script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        var name = $(this).closest('tr').children().first().text();
        // do something with 'name'
    });
});
```

Comment: You haven't got the DOM traversal quite right. See my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I keep forgetting how `first()` actually works... fixed.

Comment: Got my answer but mixing mblase75 script and Matt Ball's tip! Here's the script `var name = $(this).closest('tr').children().first().next().text();`

Answer (score 3):

You question is a bit unclear but I think this is roughly what you're looking for:

```
$('#myTable button').click(function ()
{
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr'),
        $nameTd = $tr.children('td:first'),
        name = $nameTd.text();

    alert(name);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/7XV96/

Comment: Hi, instead of getting the name, how do I get the grade?

Comment: I think it's time to [start reading the jQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com). Hint: it's [this category](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/)

Comment: Parent-Child selectors are quite confusing but I manage to figure it out. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3):

The most simplest way (in my meaning) is to use the HTML-data attributes on maybe your TR element and have all that data there, then you could just use `$(this).closest("tr").data("name");`
 like:

```
<tr data-name="bob" data-grade="1.0">
    <!-- all your td-elements -->
</tr>
<tr data-name="jack" data-grade="2.0">
    <!-- all your td-elements -->
</tr>
```

Comment: You use that word 'simple'. I do not think it means what you think it means.

Answer (score 1):

Your js should be:

```
$(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        var text= $(this).parent().siblings('td:first').text();
    });
});
```

Comment: Using `parent()` will select the TD around the button, not the TR around the TDs.

Comment: I think you mean `.siblings` since the parent of the button is a `td`.